# how to get values from query string on page load using javascript in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've a form like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 $(function(){
      $('#week1').change(function(){
    //alert('week1');
    //$("#week2").val("");
          $('#week2 option').each(function(){
              if($(this).prop('defaultSelected')) 
                  $('#week2').val($(this).val()).selectmenu("refresh");
          });
     });


     $('#week2').change(function(){
   //alert('week1');
   //$("#week1").val("");
         $('#week1 option').each(function(){
              if($(this).prop('defaultSelected')) 
                  $('#week1').val($(this).val()).selectmenu("refresh");
          });
     });
 });
</script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Search database</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form id="search" method="get" action="result.html">
      <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="week1">Select Week1</label>
        <select name="week1" id="week1">
          <option value="" selected>Select week1</option>
    <option value="mon">Monday</option>
          <option value="tue">Tuesday</option>
          <option value="wed">Wednesday</option>
          <option value="thu">Thursday</option>
          <option value="fri">Friday</option>
          <option value="sat">Saturday</option>
          <option value="sun">Sunday</option>
        </select>
  <br >
        <label for="week2">Select Week2</label>
        <select name="week2" id="week2">
          <option value=""selected>Select week2</option>
    <option value="mon">Monday 2</option>
          <option value="tue">Tuesday 2</option>
          <option value="wed">Wednesday 2</option>
          <option value="thu">Thursday 2</option>
          <option value="fri">Friday 2</option>
          <option value="sat">Saturday 2</option>
          <option value="sun">Sunday 2</option>
        </select>  
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

that submit the form to results.html and I'm trying to display the values from the query string as the page load but it is not working. When I manually refresh the page, I see the values but not when the form is submitted and results.html page is loaded. Can someone help me.

Thanks in advance for your time and advice.

Joe Green

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
         return pair[1];
      }
    }
    alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
  }
  
  document.write("<br />Week1 = " + getQueryVariable("week1"));
  document.write("<br />Week2 = " + getQueryVariable("week2"));
  </script>

<script>
    var week1 = getQueryVariable("week1");
 var week2 = getQueryVariable("week2");
 
 document.getElementById("week1").innerHTML = week1;
 document.getElementById("week2").innerHTML = week2;
 
 alert(week1);
 alert(week2);
 
  </script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Search database</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div id="week1"></div>
   <div id="week2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So is the query variable part not working?

Comment: After the form is submitted, the results.html page is loaded, when results.html page is loaded, I want to display the values of parameters in query string. I don't see them until I manually refresh the results.html page.  I don't want to manually refresh the page.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and then fetch the URL params by

```
window.onload = function(){
     var week1 = getParameterByName("week1");
     var week2 = getParameterByName("week2");
     alert(week1+"   "+week2);
};
```

Comment: With your code also I've manually refresh the page to see the values of query string parameters.

Comment: Yes it is. In fact I even tried calling a function on unload but that didn't work.

Comment: Same result with the updated code. It works when the page is manually loaded.

Comment: I'm using jQuery Mobile as this is an iPhone app being developed in Phonegap. Is jQuery Mobile causing this problem.